# Is there a limit in firebase realtime database integer data type? Large value set is auto round off sometimes

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever I set a large value eg: 293844625770502555 to firebase realtime db via firebase console/SDK, it is auto round off to another value eg: 293844625770502500.

Anyone has any idea what could be wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've exceeded the limits of JavaScript numbers (2^53).

You need to use either to make use of classes like `BigInt` and/or force Firebase to store the value as a string by adding a letter to the front like `"n293844625770502555"` and then manually convert the number back.

Comment: This issue also happens when I set the value via Firebase Admin Python SDK.

Comment: @Wick Regardless of which client/server SDK you use, the RTDB itself is built on JavaScript.